# Listar todos os atributos "data" que contenham determinado código

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, atributos

Preciso listar todos os atributos `data` que contenham determinado código em seu nome (**não no valor**).

Exemplo da tag HTML com os atributos:

```
<input type="hidden" id="products-end" data-flavor-id-15515-1="abc" data-flavor-pr-15515-1="abc" data-flavor-id-15515-2="abc" data-flavor-pr-15515-2="abc">
```

Ao pesquisar por `15515-1` ele traria todos os dados relacionados com suas respectivas informações, no caso, o `abc` (que coloquei apenas para teste).

Estou usando jQuery e utilizando `attr()` para inserir, porém, posso alternar para o `data()` caso seja necessário.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com este pequeno *snipet* você consegue listar todos os atributos com `data` no começo do nome no console, a partir daí você pode adapta-lo para suas necessidades:

```
var item = $("#products-end");
$(item[0].attributes).each(function() { 
    if(this.name.indexOf('data-') == 0){
        console.log(this.name+':'+this.value);
    }
});
```

O que ele faz é realizar um loop com todos os atributos de um certo elemento, e filtra listando apenas os que começão com `data-`, a partir daí pode-se fazer qualquer coisa com eles.

Comment: Olá, Alan. Obrigado utilizei seu método e deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Desenvolvi um métodos para você fazer isto, em javascript puro. Sobre a performance, não fiz nenhum teste.

**Método**: JavaScript puro, usando a função `document.getElementsByTagName('*');` para pegar todos os elementos da pagina, passando por dois `loops`, o primeiro verifica elementos e o segundo seus atributos. Passando uma expressão regular como parâmetro, a função faz um `match()` verificando se o atributo é válido e no caso abaixo retornando todos os elementos cuja o atributo possua `data` e `2013` (2013 é o código diferenciado do nome do atributo).

```
function getByAttr(regx) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'), function(elem) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem.attributes, function(attr) {
            if(attr.name.indexOf('data') != -1 && attr.name.match(regx)) {
                console.log(elem);
            }
        });
    });
}
getByAttr(/2013/);
```

> Veja o método funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/yvnffwrs/)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Não cheguei testar pois ja deu certo do @AlanRezende, mas agradeço de qualquer forma.